# Are Tor and BitTorrent somehow related?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bittorrent, darknet

Both Tor and BitTorrent contain the same three-letter word, so based on whatever etymology, is there some sort of association they share, not just in syntax but in computing architecture or founding principles?

If so this would be ironic given that running BitTorrent on Tor does not offer any anonymity enhancements due to them being incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no association between the two in any form (etymological, architectural, etc). Both Tor and BitTorrent were created around the same time (early 2000s), but for entirely different purposes (peer-to-peer file sharing vs anonymous Internet connections) and using entirely different designs.